# Positioning an image with text inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Kindly have a look at the image below

[image]

The feature 1 and feature 4 are two different div's that I have in bootstrap class `.col-md-4`

**Below is the html code**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="feature-group-1">
        <div class="feature-1">
            <div class="feature-1-img">
                <img src="images/cloud.png"/>
            </div>
            <div class="feature-1-writing"> 
                <h4>Feature 1</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="feature-2">
            <div class="feature-2-img">
                <img src="images/fork.png"/>
            </div>
            <div class="feature-2-writing">
                <h4>Feature 4</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Since both the blocks are in same `.col-md-4` div class of bootstrap, I am facing difficulty to bring the text and the image side by side.

I want it to look something like this

[image]

Can anyone help me out on, how to position two div's one with an image and other with a text inside the same bootstrap class side by side
I tried inline method, float etc. But no use.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It could be the image being too big to fit all in it. Or check if you put the float:left attribute on the image/text and not on the main div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post the CSS you have for feature-1, feature-1-img and feature-1-writing?

**EDIT**

Ok here is something to start with. I've used fixed widths but you could change to % if that fits your needs better

```css
body {
    background-color:#42B8DC;
    color: #fff;
    min-width:850px
}

h4 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.services {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    font-size:30px;
    padding-left:20px;
    border-bottom:3px solid #fff;
}

.feature-1, .feature-2 {
    width:300px;
    height:128px; /* height of cloud img */
    float:left;
}

.feature-1-img, .feature-2-img {
    float:left;
}

.feature-1-writing, .feature-2-writing {
    height:128px; /* height of cloud img */
}
```

```html
<div class="services">
    OUR<br/>SERVICES.
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="feature-group-1">
        <div class="feature-1">
            <div class="feature-1-img">
                <img src="http://cdn-img.easyicon.net/png/11136/1113608.gif"/>
            </div>
            <div class="feature-1-writing"> 
                <h4>Feature 1</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="feature-2">
            <div class="feature-2-img">
                <img src="http://cdn-img.easyicon.net/png/11136/1113608.gif"/>
            </div>
            <div class="feature-2-writing">
                <h4>Feature 4</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: There is no css I have written yet! apart from the html, its naturally aligned the way you are seeing in the image through bootstrap.

Comment: Edited my answer to give you a start

Comment: Okay so this is awesome, thanks for the reply. But I did something else using bootstrap grid options. didn't had to deal with css. Both the feature div i.e., with class feature-1 and feature-2. I further divided it into col-md-4 and col-md-8 class. And it worked like charm. Thanks for the reply though. I will mark it as correct :)

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it sorted :)